# Unable to loop selection in certain mesh

Tags: edges, loop

I am a beginner. Today I met a problem, for some mesh I am able to do the loop selection, for example:
[image]

But for the circle outsdie this circle I am not able to do the loop selection, I can only select two edges at a time:
[image]

Could anyone tell me why it happened? Thank you!

---

@MikoCG Also a little question to your explanation. Do you mean that if I want to be able to loop select, the polygons that are connected to the vertices(I am going to do the loop selection) should have maximal 4 vertices?
[image]

Comment: the answer is very simple, the inner loop has good topology, with quads, outer topology has the wrong topology with 5 sided ngons, this is why you cannot select loop, you need quads with only 4 vertices, not 5 vertices (if you don't want to change topology, use Ctrl + LMB to select all edges)

Comment: that said I wonder why, when you select an edge, it even selects the next one

Comment: I double click the edge(which should be the same as Alt+LMB), it then selects the edge next to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend with images:
This is your problem
[image]

It won't work if you have 5 vertices, because it probably doesn't know how to do the math behind it properly or something, anyway, an easy fix is simply to repair your topology and not make topology this way in advance to make it better, If I remove those extra 5th vertices, it works as intended:
[image]

As I said, another solution if you don't want or cannot to change topology, use Ctrl+LMB, it will select the shortest path between 2 points like this:
[image]
[image]

This can help you in this situation

Comment: Thank you a lot! The solution works.